# Rename file using a hash table

Tags: powershell

I have the following hash table.

```
$m = @{
    "AAA" = "XX";
    "BBB" = "YY";
    "CCC" = "ZZ";
    ....
}
```

I want to rename the files which names started with "AAA" to "XX....", "BBB" to "YY....", etc. 
For example, "AAA1234.txt" will be renamed to "XX1234.txt".

How to do it in Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
$m = @{"AAA" = "XX"; "BBB" = "YY"}
$files = gci *.txt
$m.GetEnumerator() | % {
    $entry = $_ # save hash table entry for later use
    $files | ? { $_.Name.StartsWith($entry.Key) } | 
        % {
            $trimmed = $_.Name.Substring($entry.Key.length) # chops only the first occurence
            $newName = $entry.Value + $trimmed
            $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName        
        }        
}
```

Comment: The name AAAAAA.txt will be renamed to XXXX.txt instead of XXAAA.txt though.

Comment: It may be a little bit easier to use regular expression `$_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace "^$($entry.Key)", $entry.Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Great..clearly explained.But this will rename the full folder name.. straight forward.

```
$m = @{"AA" = "XX"; "BB" = "YY"}
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test\ -Directory
$m.GetEnumerator() | %{Rename-Item "C:\test\$($_.Key)" -NewName "C:\test\$($_.value)" -Force
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).